# How do I reload my vimrc without leaving Vim?

Tags: vimrc

When I do a change in my `.vimrc`, I usually exit Vim and open it again. Is there an easier way to reload the new `.vimrc` changes?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Run:

```
:source $MYVIMRC
```

inside Vim to reload the `vimrc` file. Or, a shorter version:

```
:so $MYVIMRC
```

as mentioned in a comment by [kenorb](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/467/kenorb).

You may also find it useful to map either of these forms to a key. For example:

```
nnoremap <Leader>r :source $MYVIMRC<CR>
```

Comment: Shortcut: `:so $MYVIMRC`.

Comment: @kenorb: I've added this possibility; thanks for mentioning it!

Comment: `:so $m`<Tab>  ← extra-short-cut

Comment: Save two more keystrokes with `:so %`. `%` is set to the current file name of the buffer you edit, in this case `$MYVIMRC`

Comment: By far the easiest way to do this is to automatically reload the vimrc upon save - check the other answers.

Answer (score 22):

If you just want to reload the file once in a while

```
:source $MYVIMRC
```

as Paul wrote is correct. If you end up changing your vimrc often, you could add something like this to your vimrc file:

```
autocmd BufWritePost .vimrc,_vimrc source $MYVIMRC
```

This will reload the file when you write it (from within that vim session)

Comment: johannes: Do we need to edit the .vimrc through vim for this command to automatically source the file?

Comment: note a vimrc file can also be called other things: for example vimrc (if it's in ~/.vim).

Comment: @SaiManojKumarYadlapati Yes, AS said this has to be the same vom session. Bufwritepost is triggered when vom does the write

Comment: Problems with this: (1) doesn't work with `.vim/vimrc`, (2) will create duplicate `autocmd`s so each subsequent save will be slower as file will be reloaded multiple times, (3) doesn't behave with vim-tiny which doesn't have autocmd and is still the default on some linux distributions. See my answer to address these issues.

Answer (score 2):

```
" Quickly edit/reload this configuration file
nnoremap gev :e $MYVIMRC<CR>
nnoremap gsv :so $MYVIMRC<CR>
```

To **automatically** reload upon save, add the following to your `$MYVIMRC`:

```
if has ('autocmd') " Remain compatible with earlier versions
 augroup vimrc     " Source vim configuration upon save
    autocmd! BufWritePost $MYVIMRC source % | echom "Reloaded " . $MYVIMRC | redraw
    autocmd! BufWritePost $MYGVIMRC if has('gui_running') | so % | echom "Reloaded " . $MYGVIMRC | endif | redraw
  augroup END
endif " has autocmd
```

and then for the last time, type:

```
:so %
```

The next time you save your `vimrc`, it will be automatically reloaded.

**Features:**

- Tells the user what has happened (also logging to `:messages`)
- Handles various names for the configuration files
- Ensures that it wil only match the actual configuration file (ignores copies in other directories, or a `fugitive://` diff)
- Won't generate an error if using `vim-tiny`

Of course, the automatic reload will only happen if you edit your `vimrc` in vim.