# How can I reload my .vimrc without appending anything to my current settings?

Tags: vimrc, neovim

I'm aware of [this question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/24/how-do-i-reload-my-vimrc-without-leaving-vim), but sourcing that way is not the same as restarting Vim.  I want to do that without restarting Vim.

Like, if you have `set fo+=c` in your `vimrc` then re-sourcing changes it to something like this:

```
fo=<default_values>,c,c
```

How can I avoid this behavior? Is there any default config inside Vim that I could source before `vimrc` to get the same effect as a clean restart?

I'm using neovim.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have not tried it, and I would not be surprised if it has some unexpected side effects, but you could try to add

```
set all&
```

at the top of your `.vimrc` file. This will reset all options to their default setting, cf. [`:h :set-&`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#:set-&).

In particular, I am not sure how well this will work with respect to plugins. That is, some/many plugins set some vim options, and if you reset all options in your `.vimrc` file, and then resource the `.vimrc` file, then this might affect one or more of your active plugins.

A workaround might be to parse the output of `:scriptnames` and reload each of the loaded scripts in the given order. This should be done after the `.vimrc` file has been reloaded, and it should only happen after reloading, not upon restarting.

Answer (score 4):

That is no problem:

> :se[t] {option}+={value}
>
> Add the {value} to a number option, or append
>   the {value} to a string option.  When the option is a comma separated
>   list, a comma is added, unless the value was empty. If the option is a
>   list of flags, superfluous flags are removed.  **When adding a flag that
>   was already present the option value doesn't change**.

This is described at `:h :set+=`

Comment: It does with the option formatlistpat that has a regex value, and there is others options that is does too.

Comment: @MaikoID that is a string option. It does not really make sense to use :set+= for that setting.