# Why cannot I source vimrc for the current file being editing?

Tags: vimrc, load

And I add this in the vimrc file:

```
autocmd FileType markdown iabbrev mkdc <!--i--><left><left><left>
```

What I want to do is source the vimrc and make the abbreviation effective for the current file I'm editing.

I have tried:

1. `:!sc`, `:redraw!`
2. `:source $MYVIMRC`
3. `:q` and rerun Vim

But it seems that only the last method works. Is there any way to get this to work without leaving Vim? Why doesn't the second method as stated in all other related answers work in this situation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I reload my vimrc without leaving Vim?](http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/24/how-do-i-reload-my-vimrc-without-leaving-vim)

Comment: Yeah, but maybe my problem is not the same as that one since I've tried the methods in those answers.

Comment: Try #2 after starting vim with `vim -u NONE`. Odds are there's either something in your vimrc or plugins that's messing with it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your autocommand is executed when the `FileType` event is triggered, with the `markdown` value. Sourcing your `vimrc` is not enough because it only adds the autocommand but the event is not triggered.

What you need to do is:

1. Source your `vimrc` with `:source $MYVIMRC`, this will add your autocommand to the existing ones.
2. Reload your current buffer with `:e`, this will trigger the `FileType` event and thus run your autocommand.

---

Also, adding half-understood `FileType` autocommands to your `vimrc` is *not* a good way to get filetype-specific settings/mappings/abbreviations/commands/whatever.

Instead, you should use the built-in filetype detection and put your filetype-specific stuff in proper *ftplugins*:

- in `~/.vimrc`:

  ```
  filetype plugin indent on
  ```
- in `~/after/ftplugin/markdown.vim`:

  ```
  iabbrev <buffer> mkdc <!--i--><left><left><left>
  ```

Answer (score 1):

`command! Sov source $MYVIMRC | e %`

`:Sov`

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! In general, good answers provide not just code snippets, but explanations of what the code does and how to use it, as well as why it's needed.